# create a css dynamically using image and hover image

Tags: php, html, css

I am working in a `php` language . In my database there are normal image and a hover image . I know how to call it from the database but i don't know how to make class so that if i have 2 entries in my database for each ie normal image and hover image and by calling it from the db it will act as a 2 button image with the hover image  because I have 2 `rows` in my `column`

I have defined it in between head .

```
<style>
.n1{background:url(../images/no.png); 
 width:110px; height:29px; 
 float:left;
 margin-top:6px
 }

 .n1:hover{
  background:url(../images/no-h.png);
   }
 </style>
```

Comment: What have you attempted in PHP. This doesn't tell us anything really

Comment: @AndyHolmes I am stuck at this point only dat how can i used  my db values in the css

Comment: Please give a better explanation about what you want to do.

Comment: I guess some "." Characters in your text might help the most of us to understand your question better. please improve!

Comment: I have a simple image and a hover image in my db , i want to call it from the db and it will act as a button image

Comment: Create an if statement that pulls the 2 rows from the database and create inline styling using that. Pretty sure you will need to do it inline

Comment: please can u give me some example , coz i have never done this

Comment: No, you need to try something first. This isn't a code request site. Create an if statement, pull values from database, create inline css classes using that information. That should give you some base info to build on

Answer (score 0):

If you are using inline styles, then you can just use this:

```
<?php $var = 'no'; ?>
<style>
  .n1{background:url(../images/<?php echo $var ?>.png); 
 width:110px; height:29px; 
 float:left;
 margin-top:6px
 }

 .n1:hover{
  background:url(../images/<?php echo $var ?>-h.png);
   }
</style>
```

Comment: No i am not using inline styles .......I am using internal css between my head part

Comment: Also known as... Inline style

Comment: Inline style is mostly written in the tag itself in the style attribute. This style is called `internal` or `embedded` style.

Comment: if i have 2 rows and I want to make a new class for every row ......IS there any way to it

Comment: call the info from data base and create classes using a foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamics CSS using the below

```
Define Content-Type on the top of your .css.php file:
<?
header('Content-Type: text/css');
// print out your php-driven css...
?>
 and call the file like this ..

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="CSS_PATH/name-of-file.css.php">
```